# Number of ways 1a,1b,5 can add up to n (with this being a permutation)

Tags: permutations, recurrence-relations

This problem is on my homework.

A vending machine dispensing books of stamps accepts $\$ $ 1 coins, $ \$1 $ bills and $ \$5 $ bills.

A) Find a recurrence relation for the number of ways to deposit n dollars in the vending machine, where the order in which the coins and bills are deposited matters.

The book says the recurrent relation is $ a_n = 2a_{n-1}+a_{n-5}$ for $  n \ge 5 $ which is the ultimate answer to the question, but I am stuck on the middle which is figuring the iterations.

So based on the recurrent relation these are the answers
$a_0 = 1$,
$a_1 = 2$,
$a_2 = 4$,
$a_3 = 8$,
$a_4 = 16$,
$a_5 = 33$,
$a_6 = 68$,
$a_7 = 140$,
$a_8 = 288$,
$n_9 = 592$

How can I find the number of permutations? for example I would think

$a_7 = 2^7+ 2^3$ but that equals $136$ not $140$

Comment: If $\$7$ were made up of only coins and $\$1$ bills, then there would be $2^7 = 128$ ways to do it. If there were a $\$5$ bill in the mix, then there are two coins / $\$1$ bills, which makes for $2^2 = 4$, as well as $3$ possible places in that order you could place the $\$5$ bill; you could go either $511$, $151$ or $115$. That makes it $4\cdot 3 = 12$ ways of making $\$7$ if a $\$5$ bill is involved. In total, $128 + 12 = 140$.

Comment: Do you know how to find the recurrence?

Comment: @columbus8myhw not an easy way no, I didn't get that far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to build the recurrence relation and then you need to solve that.

**Recurrence relation:**

Let $a_n$ be the number of ways to dispense $\$n$ using the given currencies. To pay $\$n$ exactly one of the following should happen:

1. Suppose $\$n-1$ have been paid then to pay the total amount $\$n$, the last denomination used can be $\$1$ coin.
2. Suppose $\$n-1$ have been paid then to pay the total amount $\$n$, the last denomination used can be $\$1$ bill.
3. Suppose $\$n-5$ have been paid then to pay the total amount $\$n$, the last denomination used can be $\$5$ bill.

The number of ways in which the first two cases can happen is $a_{n-1}$ and the number of ways in which the last case can happen is $a_{n-5}$. Thus
$$a_n=2a_{n-1}+a_{n-5}.$$

**Solving the recurrence relation:**

Let us assume that the solution is of the form $a_n=r^n$. Then substituting this into the recurrence relation yields:
$$r^{n}=2r^{n-1}+r^{n-5}.$$
This results in:
$$r^5=2r^{4}+1.$$
Now solutions to this will help you construct the closed form of $a_n$.